# Active Directory Naming

Tags: active-directory

I have a test active directory domain named `ad.example.com` and have joined some Windows clients stations to the AD domain.

I'm able to log on the client station as `AD\username`. However, when I try to access protected IIS resource on the the DC (`dchostname.ad.example.com`) I have to use `EXAMPLE\username` because `AD\username` does not work.

Why is this the case? I want to be able to logon to the IIS resource as the logged on user `AD\username`. Am I missing any setting in IIS to be able to use `AD\username` to access it?

[Additional Information]
The server is `Windows Server 2008 R2` with `IIS 7`. The client is `Windows 7`. Netbios name is `dchostname`. The protected resouce being accessed is `ADFS trust points` hosted under `IIS Default Web Site` to test single signon. As you can tell this is a test setup so I'm not too concerned about sharing on the DC.

In my other setup where the domain name is simply `example.com` everything works as expected. I'm trying to understand what is different about naming a domain `ad.example.com` and why that behaves differently. In this case is the domain `AD` being considered a subdomain? This is the only domain in the forest.

Comment: One or more AD groups must be granted permissions in IIS as well as the resource on the filesystem. What do the permissions look like, what version of Windows? Not enough information.

Comment: What is the NETBIOS name of your domain?

Comment: I've added [Additional Information] to my original post. I'm not accessing file shares, but rather ADFS trust points as part of single signon.

Answer (score -2):

Check permissions: who's allowed to use these shares.
Also, sharing something on DC is the bad idea.

Comment: There are things that need to be shared on the DC, such as the `netlogon` and `sysvol` shares. DFS roots also sometimes show up on domain controllers, as to certificate server resources (like the root certificate). So whilst you shouldn't use your DC as a general purpose file server, it's not unheard of to have shared folders on there.

Comment: @MarkHenderson see, the q's author explicitly connects to `dchostname.ad.example.com`. Netlogon, sysvol and DFS should not be accessed as "host's shares", instead they must be accessed as "domain's shares", regardless of their physical location, aren't they?